# Variable search query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a GridView that will have multiple search options.

```
Call Date
Start_Time (between two time values)
Call_Time
AgentID
Phone
```

What they want is all of these options available to search by with a single search button.

What I am having trouble with is how to build the query to be dynamic so if they only search by one option it will search by that, if they search by three of the above it will still provide accurate results.

Here is the Query so far:

```
        SELECT *, 'file://///server/folder/' + replace(call_date, '/', '') + '/' 
+ qa_status + '.vox' as url FROM [JM_NSC_Recordings] WHERE ([areacode] + [phone] = @phone)

Phone = [areacode] + [phone] // @phone
Start Time = between [start_time] and [start_time] @starttime
Call Time = [call_time] // @calltime
AgentID = [tsr]  // @agentid
Call Date = [call_date] // @calldate
```

All of these fields in the database are VARCHAR

Answer (score 0):

I used a StringBuilder for same type of advance search in which there are multiple parameters.

```
StringBuilder stmt=new StringBuilder();
stmt.AppendLine("select * from table where ");

if(phone not blank)
stmt.AppendLine("phone=89754654 and ");
else
stmt.AppendLine("true and ");



if(agentid not blank)
    stmt.AppendLine("agentid=89754654 and");
    else
    stmt.AppendLine("true and ");

 else 
  stmt.AppendLine("true ");
```

and so on try it will work

Comment: Was tryign to avoid doing a lot of work in the code behind.  Was able to find a SQL based solution `WHERE (@phone is null or [areacode] + [phone] = @phone)`